# Why don't derived classes have access to base class static methods?

Tags: c++, inheritance, static-methods

Why doesn't [the following code](http://ideone.com/KHUZ43) work?

```
class A
{
   static void Method() { std::cout << "method called."; }
};

class B : public A
{
   // Has a bunch of stuff but not "Method"
};

int main()
{
   B::Method();
}
```

I know I could make it work by adding the following to B, but it would be nice if this weren't necessary, especially if there were several classes that derived from A.

```
   static void Method() { A::Method(); }
```

Comment: @jthill you're right. If it's public, it works just fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Members of classes declared with the `class` key are private by default. To make them public, you have to say:

```
class A
{
    public:
//  ^^^^^^^
        static void Method() { cout << "method called."; }
};
```

Comment: My question has been edited. Even when explicitly made public, I'm still not able to access this method.

Comment: Do you mean to call `B::Method` in `main` and not `derived::Method`

Comment: @SteveJessop You're right. My bad. The errors have been fixed.

Comment: @KerrekSB I lied. I made it public and then it worked.

Comment: You'd better make it "protected" instead of "public".